# Failed to connect to bitbucket.org port 443 Сеть недоступна

Tags: git

Пытаюсь залить изменения на удалённый репозиторий, но при попытке пишет ошибку:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://bitbucket.org/***:  
Failed to connect to bitbucket.org port 443: Сеть недоступна
```

Нагуглил по этому [что-то про прокси](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356502/github-failed-to-connect-to-github-443-windows-failed-to-connect-to-github), но с моим знанием английского и уровнем перевода в google translate осознать суть ответа не получается.

Comment: Попробуйте отключить IPv6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Собственно, ошибка говорит Вам о том, что git не может соединиться с сервером bitbucket.org

Проверьте что работает DNS и Сеть, выполнив, к примеру, ping bitbucket.org.
Если будет unable to resolve, то не работает DNS. Если будет Host is unreacheble, то dns работает, но интернета нет. Также есть вариант что у Вас закрыт порт 443 на шлюзе.

Answer (score -1):

Имя пользователя не забыли ?

```
git@bitbucket.org:<accountname>/<reponame>.git
ssh://git@bitbucket.org/<accountname>/<reponame>.git
https://<accountname>@bitbucket.org/<accountname>/<reponame>.git
ssh://git@altssh.bitbucket.org:443/accountname/reponame/
```

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-the-ssh-protocol-with-bitbucket-cloud-221449711.html